# WCF - Returning HTTP 204 throws exception causing a body to be sent

Tags: wcf, http

I have implemented a RESTful service using WCF. One of the requirements is that the service resides on a different server (or at least port) from the website that will be consuming it.

To this end I have implemented custom message inspector - not really my work but I managed to put something together from a few different sources. One is [here](http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html) the other I can't find right now.

Basically this is so that I can say that the origin of the sender is allowed. Also, when the browser sends an `OPTIONS` request that it doesn't try to execute the method.

Everything works well except that when a 204 is returned fiddler was complaining that there is a body in the response. Upon examination I found there is an exception being thrown -

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The communication object, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.'.
```

Stack trace:

```
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfClosedOrNotOpen() 
at System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext.GetServiceInstance(Message message) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InstanceBehavior.EnsureServiceInstance(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

The code is -

```
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestHeader = request.Properties["httpRequest"] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;

        if (httpRequestHeader.Method.ToUpper() == "OPTIONS" || httpRequestHeader.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] == null)
        {
            instanceContext.Abort();
        }

        return httpRequestHeader;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestHeader = correlationState as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
        HttpResponseMessageProperty httpResponseHeader = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;

        httpResponseHeader.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,pulse-symphonycrm-userloginid,pulse-symphonycrm-domainandusername");
        httpResponseHeader.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        httpResponseHeader.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        string origin = httpRequestHeader.Headers["origin"];
        if (origin != null)
        {
            httpResponseHeader.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        }

        if (httpRequestHeader.Method.ToUpper() == "OPTIONS")
        {
            httpResponseHeader.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
        }
        else if (httpRequestHeader.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] == null)
        {
            httpResponseHeader.StatusDescription = "Unauthorized";
            httpResponseHeader.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }
    }
```

I think there must be something operating after the `instanceContext.Abort()` that is then causing the exception to be thrown and generating a body, but was unable to trace where this was coming from.

Can anyone shed some light on this and how to stop it while maintaining the headers being sent.

Comment: What is your intention? Aborting instance context is not a great idea. You can set message property that can be inspected by OperationInvoker and just not invoke the operation if property is set.

Comment: @PetarVučetin I believe without this the method was attempting to execute when the OPTIONS request was sent by the browser. As the parameters were not present this was causing an error. The idea you mentioned about not invoking the operation sounds like what I want to do. Could you elaborate on this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected and as Petar mentioned the instanceContext.Abort() was certainly at the root of the error as once I removed this the problem went away.

The method I went with in the end is to simply provide an OPTIONS equivalent method to be invoked that will return nothing when the browser sends this type of request -

```
// Note the void return type
[WebInvoke(Method = "OPTIONS", UriTemplate = "/login")]
void OptionsLogin();

[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/login", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
LogInResult LogIn(LogInInformation loginInformation);
```

This method is in addition to the one that actually does and returns something.

However I believe the best method if you have many methods that will end up getting called in this way is to implement an OperationInvoker as mentioned by Petar and as shown [here](https://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/developing-custom-operationinvoker/) that does not call the underlying method.